# How to go about adding numbers depending on boolean values

Tags: python

Let's say I have this code:

```
bool_a = True
bool_b = False
bool_c = True

sum_total = 0
if bool_a == True:
    sum_total += 13
if bool_b == True:
    sum_total += 22
if bool_c == True:
    sum_total += 40
```

Is this the most Pythonic way of doing this, or is there a less redundant and more compact way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 3):

There are probably many ways to do this, but IMO what is missing here is to use containers to avoid the multiple tests:

```
bools = [bool_a, bool_b, bool_c]
# or better, if possible
# bools = [True, False, True]
nums  = [13, 22, 40]

sum_total = sum(n for b,n in zip(bools, nums) if b)

print(sum_total)
```

output: `53`

Also, you shouldn't compare a boolean to `True`/`False` in python. `if bool_a == True` should just be written `if bool_a`.

I think an important thing it to make your code explicitly represent the underlying concept you are working on.

Here is another example assuming your boolean represents the outcome of a test and you want to add the number ifs the test matches the expected outcome (`False`/`False` would be a match in this case). Here you could use a list of tuple with each item of the tuple representing a defined property (obtained result, expected output, value to add if result matches expected):

```
          # value expected num
outcomes= [(True,    True,  13),
           (False,   True,  22),
           (True,   False,  40),
           (False,  False, 100),
          ]

sum_total = sum(n for a,b,n in outcomes if a==b)

print(sum_total)
```

output: `113`

Comment: You reinvented `itertools.compress`.

Comment: @Kelly yes sure, that could be used in the first case (`sum(compress(nums, bools))`), but I think the idea I tried to convey is to design code based on the meaning of the data, and to use **containers** instead of multiple variables/tests.